# Making ad-hoc card charges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, credit-card

I have a requirement to make ad-hoc charges to users credit cards.  As I don't want to get anywhere near having to worry about credit card storage and all the associated stuff that comes with it I'm looking for a middleman service that would handle all this for me, ideally supplying me with an API that I can use to add/remove cards, and make charges through.

I don't need recurring billing or anything like that just a simple card store for ad-hoc charges.

Does anyone have any recommendations based on previous actual experience, or know of any that are worth looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Authorize.Net's Customer Information Manager (CIM)](http://www.authorize.net/solutions/merchantsolutions/merchantservices/cim/) does exactly what you're looking for.